# how to represent a sorted dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Im trying to sort a dictionary by the values, and i saw this post :
[Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

i need to get only the key that have the bigger values in a list,and not in tuple so I wrote this (which look a bit clumsy).
BUT if 2 keys had the same value i need to sort them in alphabet way.

this is what i tried to do :

```
import operator
final_sort=[]
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for item in sorted_x[::-1]:
    final_sort.append(item[0])
```

but this is good only for the numbers values condition.

for example :

```
inp : x = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 0}
out : ['c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your dict and the expect output?

Comment: yes I've added an example. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating a dictionary yields keys; you can pass the dictionary itself to `sorted`.

```
>>> x = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 0}
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda key: (-x[key], key))
['c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
```

Comment: This only sorts by value, while the question specifies "BUT if 2 keys had the same value i need to sort them in alphabet way." Since dictionary order is arbitrary, the current `'c', 'd'` is not guaranteed.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much.
@TigerhawkT3 thank you for the reference, that was exacly what i asked ! 
anyway thos answer is better for python 3, which didnt let me to unpack tuple like they did it the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, in 2 steps

```
>>> x = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 6, 'e': 0}
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
[('c', 6), ('d', 6), ('b', 4), ('a', 2), ('e', 0)]
>>> [x[0] for x in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)]
['c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
```

Comment: This only sorts by value, while the question specifies "BUT if 2 keys had the same value i need to sort them in alphabet way." Since dictionary order is arbitrary, the current `'c', 'd'` is not guaranteed.